# How to verify identity for google play console as individual?

Tags: google-play-console

Google play console is requesting to verify my identity.

The problem is that the verification form is asking for an organization info and docs while the account is for individual and that is provided in the account details screen.

So what am I missing? Where to go? Or how to contact google support?

Comment: I also have this issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: I have the same issue. Any help?

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. Any help please?

Comment: Once you have paid with organization profile while creating account. You need to use Google Support

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had this after emailing googleplay-developer-support@google.com. **Solution: Your payment profile shouldn't be set as organization if your developer profile is set to individual and vice-versa.**

Per checking, the payments profile associated with your account is set as an organization. You may choose to verify your account as an organization with the following documents that our system accepts: Certificate of Organization, and a valid ID of the organization's Official Representative.

If you would like to verify as an individual and change the entity type on your payments profile, you would have to create a new account in order to change from organization to individual. You may view your payments profile via pay.google.com

To change the entity type on your Payment Profile, it would need to be deleted and created again. Since a Play Console account can only be associated with one Payment Profile, it will need to be deleted and recreated as well.

To resolve the issue, we can close your Play Console account and refund the registration fee. Then, you can delete your payment profile at pay.google.com before you sign-up for a new Play Developer account. To proceed, please provide confirmation by responding with “I confirm to have my Play Console Developer account closed and have its registration fee refunded.”  Also, please remove the existing draft app from the Developer account

Comment: Were you able to use same email id again for developer account or had to use a new one?

Comment: @karto, I am the CEO of an organization set up in another country. I don't have a permit to stay in that country due to the stringent rules in place. The Verification of the company account keeps failing because they don't accept my current country's ID (of which I am a citizen).

It seems Google can't work with official representatives that reside outside of the country? Would you know anything about it?

Comment: I don't have any payment profile in the Play console. although I have one on the pay.google.com but it is also in individual. then why organiation document is needed i am not able to understand.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue recently and it turned out it was because I had an old Payment Profile with Account Type of 'Organisation'.

You need to go here: https://pay.google.com/gp/w/u/0/home/settings

Personally, I had two payment profiles; one was for an Individual and one was for an Organisation. Maybe the Organisation one was the default or whatever.
In the end I managed to close that payment profile and create a new developer account after having the first one refunded.

There were a few emails to Google Support going back and forth but that solved it in the end and now I have an app on the Play Store.

Comment: how to you able to close the payment profile and create a new developer account, i am stuck as you were, please help,

Comment: what happened to your apps? did you have to transfer them to another account? before deleting the profile?

Comment: I don't have any payment profile in the Play console. although I have one on the pay.google.com but it is also in individual. then why organiation document is needed i am not able to understand.